# Kill a process in ruby

Tags: ruby, shell

I use this code to kill a process with a PID file:

```
Process.kill 15, File.read('/tmp/pidfile').to_i
```

But the following two examples never work, when i try:

```
system "kill `cat /tmp/file.pid`"
```

or

```
`kill \`cat /tmp/pidfile\``
```

output is:

```
sh: 1: kill: Usage: kill [-s sigspec | -signum | -sigspec] [pid | job]... or
kill -l [exitstatus]
```

Is there a problem with the backstick ? because in bash this works perfectly:

```
kill `cat /tmp/file.pid`
```

Comment: Why would you want to use the `system`-based method if your first example is already working?

Comment: Just to learn and understand what is going on.

Comment: Which is the correct path? `/tmp/pidfile` or `/tmp/file.pid`? I guess the first, since in principle, there's nothing wrong with the syntax in your attempt using `system`.

Answer (score 1):

The string is not being interpolated. This does *not* run a `cat` command:

```
system "kill `cat /tmp/file.pid`"
```

Instead, you could write this as:

```
system "kill #{`cat /tmp/file.pid`}"
```

However, I'm unclear why you'd choose to do this over your original (working) method.

Comment: Im learning ruby and i ilike experiment new things (pid, trhead, work with file...) the command above produce `sh: 1: kill: No such process` of course the process is launched before.

Comment: @flowdaguerre it is because you have really no such process run

Comment: *"the command above produce sh: 1: kill: No such process"* --- Presumably this is because there is no process running with this ID! This is not a bug in the ruby code; it must be some other issue, such as the file not being updated with the current ID.

Comment: Could it be that when one of your commands succeeds, that process is no longer alive, so kill raises that error?  In other words, are you starting a new process before every test you run?  Also, though it probably isn't relevant here, you might want to check out `Shellwords.shellescape` for these kinds of things (see https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html). Apparently, a `shellescape` instance method has been added to String for convenience.